# This simple Javascript calendar does not work in IE 9/10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am using the simple javascript calendar in a website I have created.  This page has a live demo of the plugin:

http://www.electricprism.com/aeron/calendar/

I am using the second one.

This is working fine in Chrome, Firefox and Opera but it does not work in Internet Explorer 9/10 unless I enable compatibility mode (which then breaks my layout).

In IE, the calendar button does not appear at all.

How can I get this to work in IE9/10?

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you try jqUI date picker instead.
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: That's my backup plan but it would be a lot easier for me if I could just do something small to get this one working in IE for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the version of mootools which is loaded on that site, it is using `1.2.1` but looking at mootools it seems the current version is `1.4.5`. The next thing I noticed was that in IE9 there's a JavaScript error:

> SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5) 
>   mootools.js, line 15 character 20608

From that looks if it there's something up with the minification that was used.

I've done a test of the same site using mootools `1.4.5` (using the [Fiddler2 AutoResponder](http://fiddler2.com/)) and the JavaScript error went away and the button appeared with the calendar working.

So if you upgrade to mootools `1.4.5` it should be fine.